# PHP Fatal error:Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'new-project/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in E:\new-project\artisan:18

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan, autoload

I want to create new laravel project by composer. I use `composer create-project laravel/laravel new-project` command for create new project. then, my project is created following this picture.

[image]

I start Laravel's local development server using the Laravel's Artisan CLI serve command (first `cd new-project` and then `php artisan serve` command). But I got the following error.

[image]

Why is there no vendor folder in this project?!!!
How do I fix this error?

*(I used PHP 8.1.10)*

Comment: Maybe change the phrasing in the title. It reads like you're asking how to prevent it from being created while the question asks why it wasn't. Did you get any errors or anything when you ran `composer create-project laravel/laravel new-project`?

Comment: please retry after `composer install`

Answer (score 6):

You need to issue `composer install` to install packages which creates the vendor/ folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the `vendor` folder if you already have one in your project, and run `composer install`.
Then restart your server.